# I do not see my pen drive in the system after I have formatted it

Tags: error-handling, usb-drive

Today I tried formatting for my pen drive. Then it shows an error message that is "could not be formatted". After this process my pen drive is not visible in the desktop or launcher panel.

Haw can I fix this?

Comment: open `disks` and see for pendrive , is it there ?

Comment: unplug it and plug it back in. when you perform formatting, the device is unmounted and will remain unmounted until you unplug the device and then plug it back in.

Comment: What is "ould not formatted"?

Answer (score 1):

Unplug it and plug it back in.

When you perform formatting, the device is unmounted and will remain unmounted until you unplug the device and then plug it back in.